# C++ : extracting string from between two symbols

Tags: c++, string, search

I have the string 
    String str = "my age is how old i am?how old are you?";

And I want to extract just the string "how old are you" and place it in another variable.

How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get a part of the a string in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498119/how-do-i-get-a-part-of-the-a-string-in-c)

Comment: `str.Substring( 0, str.Length - 2 )`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the substring method:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/

```
int first = str.find('?')
String ageStr = str.substr(first, str.find('?', first) - first);
```

This way you select the part of the string between the position of the first question mark, and the position of the second question mark...

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
string  GetStringInBetween(string Src,string FirstTag, string Secondag)
{
    size_t FirstPos,SecondPos;
    string newstr="";
    FirstPos = Src.find(FirstTag);
    if (FirstPos != string::npos)
    {
        FirstPos++;
        SecondPos = Src.find(Secondag, FirstPos );
        if (SecondPos != string::npos)
        {
            newstr = Src.substr(FirstPos , SecondPos - FirstPos);
        }
    }
    return newstr;
}
int main()
{

    string str = "?how old are you?";
    string nstr = GetStringInBetween(str, "?", "?");
    cout << nstr;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0;i<strlen(str);i++)
{
    if(str[i] != '?')
    {
        cout<<str[i];
    }
}
```

You can add any symbol of your choice in place of `?`.

Comment: You should explain more about what this code is doing.