# Copy 80 bit hex number from char array to uint16_t vector or array

Tags: c++, arrays, hex

Say I have a text file containing the 80bit hex number

```
0xabcdef0123456789abcd
```

My C++ program reads that using `fstream` into a char array called `buffer`.
But then I want to store it in a `uint16_t` array such that:

```
uint16_t * key = {0xabcd, 0xef01, 0x2345, 0x6789, 0xabcd}
```

I have tried several approaches, but I continue to get decimal integers, for instance:

```
const std::size_t strLength = strlen(buffer);
std::vector<uint16_t> arr16bit((strLength / 2) + 1);

for (std::size_t i = 0; i < strLength; ++i)
{
    arr16bit[i / 2] <<= 8;
    arr16bit[i / 2] |= buffer[i];
}
```

Yields:

```
arr16bit = {24930, 25444, 25958, 12337, 12851}
```

There must be an easy way to do this that I'm just not seeing.

Here is the full solution I came up with based on the comments:

```
int hex_char_to_int(char c) {
    if (int(c) < 58) //numbers
        return c - 48;
    else if (int(c) < 91) //capital letters
        return c - 65 + 10;
    else if (int(c) < 123) //lower case letters
        return c - 97 + 10;
}
uint16_t ints_to_int16(int i0, int i1, int i2, int i3) {
    return (i3 * 16 * 16 * 16) + (i2 * 16 * 16) + (i1 * 16) + i0;
}

void readKey() {
    const int bufferSize = 25;
    char buffer[bufferSize] = { NULL };
    ifstream* pStream = new ifstream("key.txt");
    if (pStream->is_open() == true)
    {
        pStream->read(buffer, bufferSize);
    }
    cout << buffer << endl;
    const size_t strLength = strlen(buffer);
    int* hex_to_int = new int[strLength - 2];
    for (int i = 2; i < strLength; i++) {
        hex_to_int[i - 2] = hex_char_to_int(buffer[i]);
    }
    cout << endl;
    uint16_t* key16 = new uint16_t[5];
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        key16[i] = ints_to_int16(hex_to_int[j++], hex_to_int[j++], hex_to_int[j++], hex_to_int[j++]);
        cout << "0x" << hex << key16[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

This outputs:

```
0xabcdef0123456789abcd

0xabcd 0xef01 0x2345 0x6789 0xabcd
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use `i / 4` if you want to use four characters from the text file for each element in `arr16bit`?

Comment: Also what happens with the characters `'0'` and `'x'` at the beginning of the text file? I don't see them being ignored anywhere in the code.

Comment: `a` is ascii `0x61`.  `b` is ascii `0x62`.  `0x6162` = 24930.  Consider what you are doing.  Chars aren't integers.

Comment: And where do you convert characters like `'a'` or `'5'` to their actual numeric values 10 and 5?

Comment: Is this a binary file, or is that ASCII hex dumped data? Is it *literally* `"0x6162..."`?

Comment: 1. tadman I'm not sure; I may have an endian issue    2. mkrieger1 i/4 might be the right idea there         3. mkrieger1 I have ignored '0' and 'x in my ifstream read. 4. J you are correct that it is converting my chars to ints, but how can I avoid that?  5. mkrieger1 I'm not doing that, so maybe that is the way to fix it?  6. tadman it is a regular text file, literally 0xab...

Comment: @SteveZee It's not `0xab`.  The ascii character `a` is entirely unrelated to the hexadecimal value `0xa`.  The ascii character `a` is an entire byte and has value `0x61`.  I think if you spend some time learning about character and numeric formats this would all make much more sense.  Feels like trying to run before you can walk.

Comment: [Convert hex string (char) to int?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10156409/327083)

Comment: [How do I get a part of the a string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2498119/327083)

Comment: [Convert char to int in C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5029840/327083)

Comment: J - I understand the difference between an ascii character and a hex value, I just thought there might be a way to read it as a literal hex value, but since that doesn't seem to be the case I am just going to add a step and convert the characters to integers corresponding to their literal hex values.

Comment: @SteveZee Read the links.  I'd think [`strol`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/strtol.html) would be preferred.